# Regex for a matching a sentence not containing the word 'test' in it

Tags: regex

These types of files should not get matched:

```
abcd_test.py
test.py
xyz_test.js
test.js
```

Everything else should get matched.

What would be the regex for that?

Comment: does the file names ends with `.py` or `.js`?

Comment: Can't you use a `contains`-like method? What language are you using?

Comment: Lookup negative lookaheads. But the syntax depends on the language.

Comment: @sp00m actually it's an existing tool which searches for files using regex. So can't use that.
AvinashRaj- It can be any extension actually.
Dave- It seems the answer given uses that. I'll have to read that up to make sense of the answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
(?!.*?test)^.*$
```

this should do it.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/qS7yN9/1

Comment: It uses a negative lookahead.Basically says (?!regex)regex1 == match regex1 if regex does not match.So our regex says do not match anything which has test in it.And so it goes.

Comment: If you can add the explanation of the regex it will be very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: @AbhishekNair added in comments